# How to I safely log on to gmail from an un-trusted PC?

Tags: gmail, security, passwords

I have just got back from holiday, I was not willing to check my email form the hotel’s “internet café” PC, as I could not think of a way of eliminate the risk that it had a “password logging” worm, virus, or intentionally install application.  (Someone could even have installed a hardware keyboard logger into the keyboard socket!)

So is there any way to access web applications safely from untested machines?

*(I would rather not take the risk of my laptop getting stolen on from the hotel room, and not all vacation type hotels have wireless internet yet anyway)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The password manager [LastPass](http://lastpass.com) has a [screen keyboard](http://lastpass.com/help.php?topic=virtualkeyboard) and also [one-time-use passwords](http://lastpass.com/help.php?topic=onetimepass).  The screen keyboard is specifically to avoid key loggers and one-time-use limits the value of the password if it is intercepted..

Comment: are you using it? For years I was using the PasswordSafe and I was storing the encrypted file into Dropbox.. but the version for MacOS sucks.. and maybe it's time to change..

Answer (score 4):

If you don't own the machine, there's no way to be certain that something isn't installed to capture keystrokes. I wouldn't log into a public machine to do anything other than check the news, ever.

If it's your own machine, you can use a secure (SSL/TLS) connection to your e-mail provider via someone's WiFi. That should be reasonably secure (though there's always the possibility of a man-in-the-middle attack).

Answer (score 1):

[Google 2-Step Verification](http://www.google.com/landing/2step/) would seem to be the answer.

> Signing in to your account will work a little differently
>
> 1. Enter your password
>
>    Whenever you sign in to Google, you'll enter your password as usual.
> 2. Enter a verification code
>
>    Then, you'll be asked for a code that will be sent to your phone via text, voice call, or our mobile app.

So, even if there is a keylogger, unless the bad guy can also get your phone he can't get into your account.

If you have a smartphone there's also an [app for generating the verification code](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1066447).

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using the GMail web interface, setup [SquirrelMail](http://squirrelmail.org/) (remember GMail supports IMAP) on your desktop or server and use the [one-time password plugin](http://squirrelmail.org/plugin_view.php?id=276).

Comment: As far as I can see QquirrelMail needs to be installed on my server/pc so is not a web app.

Comment: Correct . . . . .